# OrientDB Graph Editor menu button missing

Tags: orientdb

Tutorials show and use a Graph Editor but the button is not there on my OrientDB studio (server v1.7.10). Did it get removed or do I have to do something to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB Studio 1.7.x does not provide graph editor

you have to use ODB 2.x like 2.0-rc1

http://www.orientechnologies.com/download/